# Change event on a dynamically loaded option list is not called

Tags: jquery, html-select, velocity, jquery-events

I would like to load dynamically (using a velocity object) a select drop down list, and then associate the change event with it; to do it I wrote so:

```
$(function() {
        var tableList = $("#tableList");
#foreach( $i in $it.getTableNames() )
        tableList.append($("<option></option>")
            .text("$!esc.html($i)"));
#end
        tableList.change(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "$it.uri" + "/tablesColumnNames",
            dataType: "json",
            success: loadTableResponse
            });
        });
}
```

But despite the option list is correctly loaded the change event can never be triggered. What is wrong with this?

Comment: What is a Velocity Object?

Comment: Your bottom bracket needs `});` instead of `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
$(function() {
  $(document.body).on("change","#tablelits",function() {
              //...
         });
  //append your select/options whenever you want
})
```

NB:cache your `$(document.body)` obviously, the previous code is just illustration of the mechanic

NB: don't append your options one by one
create a var with all your options within your select box & then append the select at once using `appendTo` (because `append` tends to go wrong with ie)

Comment: Don't think document.body is correct all you need is `$(document)`

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch that's a philosophical debate, me cache $(document.body) in a jquery object upon dom ready to bind my events as in fact the body of the document is the big parent of the html with which user interact; never had a problem; why is it not correct ? in case you plan to bind events to your html headers (:/)? please inform us

Comment: @mikakun Here's the difference statistics-wise in case this may help :) http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector

Comment: @Jimbo  that test is between body & document.body & it happens that... document.body cached is the fatest (Testing in Firefox 18.0 on Ubuntu), so i'm not sure where you're getting at here. editing answer to insis on cache but it should be a given to anyone

Comment: I wasn't actually aware that document.body was even possible so I retract that, my bad. Actually seems like document.body is more efficient than body. http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector/6

Comment: They never compare it to `document` tho so that would be interesting to find out.

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch sorry i confuse you & Jimbo in my previous comment; nevertheless imo, semantically document.body is the most correct

Comment: No I posted that just because it was interesting, there was no point to be made.

Comment: @Jimbo yeah apo i was replying to your comment as if written by Gustavo then edited it & changed to your pseudo...), my confusion; good place to test stuff indeed thx